# Get aks nodepool / vmss subnet ID

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I created an aks using az cli with minimal parameters and specified a node-count and auto scaling. This created a nodepool and VMSS etc. and an accompanying vnet and subnet automatically.

How do I find out the created vnet and subnet using az cli?

```
az aks nodepool list --cluster-name aks -g rg-aks
```

report vnetSubnetId and podSubnetId as null.

Using
az vmss list
does show the subnet but I haven't found any properties of the vmss linking it to the nodepool or aks cluster to enable finding it.

The autogenerated name is something like:
aks-nodepool1-15343534-vmss

Which I guess I could filter for along the lines of aks-nodepool1-*-vmss but that seems dodgy and flaky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested in my environment

The VNET is created along with the VMSS in a different resource group which starts with MC_

To get the subnet ID, you can use the below script:

```
$CLUSTER_RESOURCE_GROUP = az aks show --resource-group RGName --name AKSClusterName --query nodeResourceGroup -o tsv
$VMSS_NAME = az vmss list -g $CLUSTER_RESOURCE_GROUP --query "[0].name"
az vmss show -g $CLUSTER_RESOURCE_GROUP -n $VMSS_NAME --query virtualMachineProfile.networkProfile.networkInterfaceConfigurations[0].ipConfigurations[0].subnet.id
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I wrote that I already know how to get the vnet from the VMSS. I can't see any way to get from the AKS to the VMSS however.

Comment: The vnet is created in the resource group in which VMSS is created. It is not created in the resource group of AKS cluster. So you cannot get it using az aks commands

Comment: Yes but I can't imagine there would be such a glaring omission of not being able to go from an AKS Cluster to it's auto created resources. How are simple network scripting tasks then possible? I want to add this vnet / subnets to various firewalls

Comment: I have edited my answer to get the details of VMSS RG and Name from **az aks** command and then use it in **az vmss** command

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use kubectl? Using kubectl, run

```
$nodes = kubectl get nodes -o json | ConvertFrom-Json
$scaleSets = $nodes.items.metadata.name
```

Then, $scaleSets will be something like:

```
aks-agentpool-xxxxxxxx-vmss000000
aks-agentpool-xxxxxxxx-vmss000001
aks-agentpool-xxxxxxxx-vmss000002
aks-nodepool-xxxxxxxx-vmss000000
aks-nodepool-xxxxxxxx-vmss000001
aks-nodepool-xxxxxxxx-vmss000002
```

From here, you can use .Substring() to exclude the instance id and and Get-Unique to remove duplicates.